# I want to load my custom bootstrap admin panel to codeigniter

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, codeigniter-3

I am beginner and my pages are placed `D:\wamp\www\CI\application\views\pages` and inside pages there is a file where other files are included.

How can i set their paths that this is my index file which is placed in `D:\wamp\www\CI\application\views`

```
<?php
    include("files/header.php");
    include("base_url().Admin/sidebar.php");
    include("files/handler.php");
?> 
</div>
<!-- end: PAGE -->
<!-- end: MAIN CONTAINER -->
<?php
    include("files/footer.php");
?>
```

Please help me... Thanks in advance

Comment: Please improve the formatting and explain what exactly is the problem or question to avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Including files requires relative or absolute path. You are trying to include web URL in second line. And in unappropriate way, because it need to be without wrapping quotes surrounding `base_url()` function but with append of "class/method".

Regarding your question, your are using:

```
include("base_url().Admin/sidebar.php");// wich is wrong
```

You are looking for:

```
include(FCPATH . "Admin/sidebar.php");
```

Comment: i have done like this  <?php include("pages/$pages.php");?> where is $pages are coming from the controller

Comment: Try with `$this->load->view('pages/' . $pages)`;